# How to pattern match current week's data to previous week's data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, string-matching

I am trying to find recurrent strings in every week of my data in one column, and was hoping to create a column that returned a 1 if a pattern matched and one of the cells contained the word "Unidentified" from a previous or future week, and a 0 if not. I am wondering how to create the column, "Match." Thank you for your help!

```
Week     Data              Match
 1       Red                 0
 2       Blue Unidentified   0
 3       Blue                1
 4       Blue                1
 5       Green               0
 6       Yellow              0
 7       Green               0
 8       Green Unidentified  1
 9       Green               1
 10      Yellow              0
 11      Red                 0
 12      Green               0
 13      Orange              0
 14      Orange              1
 15      Orange              1 
 16      Orange Unidentified 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be curious to see more concise approaches, but I hope this is clear:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Data_unid = Data %>% stringr::str_remove(" Unidentified"),
         group = cumsum(Data_unid != lag(Data_unid, default = ""))) %>%
  mutate(has_unid = any(Data != Data_unid), .by = group) %>%
  mutate(match2 = 1 * (Data_unid == lag(Data_unid) & has_unid))
```

Result

```
   Week                Data Match Data_unid group has_unid match2
1     1                 Red     0       Red     1    FALSE      0
2     2   Blue Unidentified     0      Blue     2     TRUE      0
3     3                Blue     1      Blue     2     TRUE      1
4     4                Blue     1      Blue     2     TRUE      1
5     5               Green     0     Green     3    FALSE      0
6     6              Yellow     0    Yellow     4    FALSE      0
7     7               Green     0     Green     5     TRUE      0
8     8  Green Unidentified     1     Green     5     TRUE      1
9     9               Green     1     Green     5     TRUE      1
10   10              Yellow     0    Yellow     6    FALSE      0
11   11                 Red     0       Red     7    FALSE      0
12   12               Green     0     Green     8    FALSE      0
13   13              Orange     0    Orange     9     TRUE      0
14   14              Orange     1    Orange     9     TRUE      1
15   15              Orange     1    Orange     9     TRUE      1
16   16 Orange Unidentified     1    Orange     9     TRUE      1
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response, I tried this code and the error that I am getting is that my replacement rows are less than the rows in my dataframe. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A universal approach that works with any matched word.

First `strsplit` and `unnest_wider` strings into words.

Then compare the words and see if any match in rows that are really  previous weeks. Finally replace the generated `NA`s and unselect the helper columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(spl = strsplit(as.character(Data), " ")) %>% 
  unnest_wider(spl, names_sep = "_") %>% 
  mutate(Match = (if_else(c(0, diff(Week)) == 1, 
                    if_any(starts_with("spl"), ~ .x == lag(.x)), FALSE))*1,
         Match = replace_na(Match, 0)) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("spl"))
# A tibble: 16 × 3
    Week Data                Match
   <int> <chr>               <dbl>
 1     1 Red                     0
 2     2 Blue Unidentified       0
 3     3 Blue                    1
 4     4 Blue                    1
 5     5 Green                   0
 6     6 Yellow                  0
 7     7 Green                   0
 8     8 Green Unidentified      1
 9     9 Green                   1
10    10 Yellow                  0
11    11 Red                     0
12    12 Green                   0
13    13 Orange                  0
14    14 Orange                  1
15    15 Orange                  1
16    16 Orange Unidentified     1
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response! I get the error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `spl`.
i `spl = strsplit(Data, " ")`.
x non-character argument, do you have any advice for this? Thanks again!

Comment: @ruser123 “Data” seems to contain numeric fields. A possible solution may be to use as.character. Gonna edit, see if that works for your data.

Comment: @ruser123 … but it’s kinda strange, because variables are either character or numeric, they can’t contain multiple types. Maybe it’s a factor variable… but the fix should also work in this case.

Comment: I tried the fix and this time, an error I am getting is that my replacement has less rows than my whole data frame. Do you have any advice for this? Thank you!

Comment: @ruser123 Does the code work on a subset of your data frame? E.g. `head(df) %>% mutate(...`. Maybe post a part of your data with `dput(head(df, 20))`. It's possible there's a nested list interfering.